# Camel Spring DSL is not working as expected

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-dsl

Tried to create a very simple route to read from a FTP location using Java as well as Spring DSLs.

The route created with Java DSL is working as expected.

```
from("{{ftp.server}}").to("file:target/download").log(
            "Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
```

Options:

```
ftp://x.x.x.x:21/in?username=kallada&password=kallada&passiveMode=false&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&delay=5s&move=done
```

But the route created with Spring DSL is just exiting just after logging in to the FTP server.

```
<route id="ftpSend">
    <from uri="ftp://kallada@x.x.x.x:21/in?password=kallada&amp;passiveMode=false&amp;binary=true&amp;delay=6000&amp;localWorkDirectory=/tmp"/> 
    <to uri="file://target/download"/> 
</route>
```

I'm using a locally installed FTP server (FileZilla) to test this application. Afs ter invoking the route created with the Spring DSL the program is just exiting. Please see the console log attached.

```
05:06:04.402 INFO  [main][org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter] Loaded 176 type converters
05:06:04.896 INFO  [main][org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
05:06:05.156 INFO  [main][org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] Route: ftpSend started and consuming from: Endpoint[ftp://kallada@127.0.0.1:21/in?binary=true&delay=6000&localWorkDirectory=%2Ftmp&passiveMode=false&password=xxxxxx]
05:06:05.171 INFO  [main][org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
05:06:05.174 INFO  [main][org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] Apache Camel 2.12.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.272 seconds
```

Beyond this point the program just exits.

Please see the FTP server console log also.

```
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:45 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> PWD
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> CWD in
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 250 CWD successful. "/in" is current directory.
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> PORT 127,0,0,1,251,174
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 200 Port command successful
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> LIST
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/in"
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 226 Successfully transferred "/in"
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> CWD /
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:50 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(000079)24-11-2014 05:02:53 - kallada (x.x.x.x)> disconnected.
```

Any pointers to solve this issue would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: How did you start the spring?

Comment: @WillemJiang     
    import rg.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class TestTransfer {

 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/camel-spring-context.xml");
        }
 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main just exit after starting the camel context. Please check out [this](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html) for Running Camel standalone and keeping it running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the case is the same as you explained. I'm invoking the camel route from  camel-spring-context.xml as a classpath resource. But as soon as I invoke the file, the program is exiting. Is there a way to load the routes from the spring DSL file (Camel) and keep it running?

Comment: My Spring DSL based application is just exiting once it is invoked. But if I change the application to use the FILE end points , the application just works fine.Or if I change it to JAVA DSL also the application works fine.

Comment: To add some more clarity, my application is a standalone one, created with camel 2.10.2. As fter running the application, it says      [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - ftp://kallada@x.x.x.x:21/in][org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer] Connected and logged in to: ftp://kallada@x.x.x.x:21 and with out initializing the file transfer,  will just shutdown.

Comment: You can using the Main class in the camel-spring to load the application, please take a look at this page http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html for more information.